# can't get string result of replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is what I'm trying to do:

```
var x = $("<div><div class='aaa' /></div>").find('.aaa').replaceWith("hi");
alert(x);
```

the result of the alert is `object` I need `<div>hi</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.replaceWith` returns removed element, so you need to save your initial object. Also you can't rely on `outerHTML` property of the element.

```
var x = $("<div><div class='aaa' /></div>");
x.find('.aaa').replaceWith("hi");
var div = x.get(0);
alert("<" + div.tagName + ">" + div.innerHTML + "</" + div.tagName + ">");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.end()` to close the `find` operation, so that you can access the modified content.

```
var x = $("<div><div class='aaa' /></div>").find('.aaa').replaceWith("hi").end();
```

`x` is a jQuery object, that's why you are getting `[object Object]`. You can access it's content directly as `x[0]` or `x.get(0)`.

You can test your expected result using the following statement,

```
alert(x[0].outerHTML);
```

Note that `outerHTML` is not supported in Firefox.